# What's the best setup for working with WSO2 WSAS

Tags: java, eclipse, wso2, wso2-integration-studio

What version of java, eclipse and WPT should I be using?

Answer (score 1):

Java 2 SDK 5.0 or higher
The Release notes tell you all at this site

http://wso2.org/project/wsas/java/2.3/docs/tools/ide.html

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 WSAS is now called WSO2 Application Server and is now in version 4.0.0

If you are to run the latest WSO2 Application Server, it is recommended that you run it with JDK 1.6

If you want to develop services to be hosted, you can use WSO2 Carbon Studio for this purpose. Note that Carbon Studio is Eclipse based and provide the same experience as WTP.